# Mathematical notation for the maximum of a set of correlation coefficient

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, correlation

I have got a question regarding the correct mathematical notation of the following:

I have a value "alpha" that is the maximum of a set of k correlation coefficient (ρ) (calculated according to "Pearson correlation coefficient"between two time-series of yields). Each correlation coefficient has been calculated to the reference "yield_0" e.g:

correl(yield_0,yield_1)=ρ_0_1;

correl(yield_0,yield_2)=ρ_0_2;

correl(yield_0,yield_3)=ρ_0_3;

correl(yield_0,yield_4)=ρ_0_4;

So the range of ρ is between 1 and k.
Could the notation be put in such a way:

α=max{f(ρ):ρ=1,…,k}.

Comment: Math isn't a programming language. You can write whatever you want as long as your intended audience can read it. In this particular case, I'd write something like, "Let $\rho(X, Y) = \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)/\sigma_X \sigma_Y$ denote the Pearson correlation coefficient of random variables $X, Y$ (where well-defined). Put $\rho_i = \rho(y_0, y_i)$ for $i = 1, \dots, 4$ and $\alpha = \max \rho_i$.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you mate